# Infinite loop when trying to populate a list of no more than two Hospitals

Tags: java

In this project the user must enter 1 or 2 hospitals but not 3 or more. So the program starts and I display a menu. If the user presses 1 he must enter a hospital(name and department). After this the program displays the menu again  and the user can choose to insert another hospital.

But after that, if I choose to insert another one (which is not permitted) the program accepts it. It seems that every time `InsertHospitals()` is called from the main class,  the value of `numberofhospitals` (which is a counter counting how many hospitals I entered) equals 0.

```
public class Hospital {
    private String Name, Departments;
    private char flag;
    private int numberofhospitals;

    private Hospital[] ListOfHospitals;
    //private Patient[] ListOfPatiens;
    //private Doctor[] ListOfDoctors;
    //private Examination[] ListOfExaminations;
    //private Folder[] ListOfFolders;

    public Hospital(String Name, String Departments)
    {
        this.Name=Name;
        this.Departments=Departments;
    }
    public Hospital()
    {
        ListOfHospitals = new Hospital[2];
        //ListOfPatiens = new Patient[100];
        //ListOfDoctors = new Doctor[100];
        //ListOfExaminations = new Examination[100];
        //ListOfFolders = new Folder[100];
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setname(String Name)
    {
        this.Name=Name;
    }
    public String getDepartments()
    {
        return Departments;
    }
    public void setdepartments(String Departments)
    {
        this.Departments=Departments;
    }


    public void InsertHospitals()
    {
        if(numberofhospitals==2)
        {
           System.out.println("You can give only two hospitals!");

        }
        else
        {

            String temp = sir.readString("Hospital's Name:");
            Name=temp;
            String temp1 = sir.readString("Hospital's departments:");
            Departments=temp1;
            Hospital hospital = new Hospital(Name, Departments);
            ListOfHospitals[numberofhospitals]=hospital;
            numberofhospitals=numberofhospitals+1;          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The list of hospitals shouldn't be a member of the `Hospital` class. This would create a list of hospitals in each new hospital. You want to have one list.

Comment: Thank you. I thought of that too, but we are obligated to do so.It's a project and we are asked to do it this way. Is there another way?

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: Loop?  What loop?  (As an aside, if you construct your `Hospital` with any parameters, you won't have an array at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstanding something, the list of hospitals (as mentioned) should not be inside your hospital class. You have to consider your hospital class as a blueprint you are using in your application.

Which means that you need to have a list of hospitals, as a list inside your other application class (which runs the application) and the InsertHospitals method should not be in your hospital class either obviously.

As you add a new hospital in your program, you create a new hospital object and add it to the list of hospitals (fx an arraylist) your keeping as a field value.

Also posssibly make a new constructor with parameters in the hospital class so you can insert the values outside of the class.

Something like this fx.

```
public class MainApp {
    private ArrayList<Hospital> hospitalList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize or load it from a file or whatever here.
        hospitalList = new ArrayList<Hospital>();
        // your code here...
    }

    public void insertHospital(<insert parameters here to create a hospital>) {
        Hospital newHospital = new Hospital(<insert params with new constructor>);
        hospitalList.add(newHospital); 
    }
}
```

Comment: yep what he says is correct. Need two class to work this out. Have the hospital class separately and create another class with a array of two elements of hospital type in it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your problem, your program completely wrong. In `insertHospital()` your changing `Name` and `Departments` fields, and creating new `Hospital` with those values. When you print `Hospital` information all `hospitals` will have the same value.